# SQL statement question

Tags: mysql

I need to know what this part of a statement is saying:

`... or ifnull(UrinePerDay<500,1) or...`

Am I correct in assuming:

....if the value in the `UrinePerDay` database field is `400` that this returns a 'true' value?

...if there is nothing charted in the field that this returns a `1` which would also be 'true'?

... the function would return a 'false' if the value is `501` or greater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ifnull is a function that if the value of the first parameter is NULL returns the second parameter

this tells me theUrinePerDay contains nulls.

any operation done on a null returns a null,

so this is a hack around bad data entry in the database.  if UrinePerDay<500 return 1 else 0  if UrinePerDayy is null return 1

Comment: And "0" means "false"; any other number (including "1") means "true".

Comment: *any operation done on a null returns a null* That's not right statement, because NULL-safe compare operator `<=>` exists. And checking for (not-)null value using `IS [NOT] NULL` is "operation" too.

Comment: These functions are specifically created to inform that a value is null it can't do anything with it other than return a different value...     I stated an operation is DONE ON A NULL, compare a null get a null, = to a null get a null, + null  get a null, < or > get a null etc....

Answer (score 2):

Here's a summary of values

```
select version();
| version() |
| :-------- |
| 8.0.18    |

select  ifnull(499<500,1),ifnull(501<500,1),ifnull(NULL<500,1)

ifnull(499<500,1) | ifnull(501<500,1) | ifnull(NULL<500,1)
----------------: | ----------------: | -----------------:
                1 |                 0 |                  1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f0613f551fea5bc7de6036255ba2717)*